# Chemical balance problem

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The ammonium chloride dissociates at 317 ° C according to the reaction:

$$\ce{NH4Cl (s) -> HCl (g) + NH3 (g)}$$
reaching a total pressure of 500 mm Hg in equilibrium in a closed container. What will be the total pressure in the equilibrium when a gaseous hydrogen chloride at 500 mm Hg of pressure is introduced into a closed vessel together with the ammonium chloride?

What I have calculated has been:

In the first balance. 
$$\ce{Kp=pHCl*pNH3}$$
$$\ce{pHCl=pNH3=P/2}$$
$$\ce{Kp=(p^2/4)=(500/760)^2/4=0,108}$$

And in the second balance, when is added 500 mm Hg of HCl 
$$\ce{Kp=p(2p)^2=4p^3}$$
$$\ce{pT=p + 2p=3p}$$

And now I don't know what else to do.

Sorry if the formulas are not well placed

Comment: In the second balance, where did the $\rm2p$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, both pressures of $\ce{NH_3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ are $250$ Torr = $0.329$ atm. So that the equilibrium constant is $K_p$ = ($0.329$ atm$)^2$ = $0.108$ atm$^2$

After addition of $500$ Torr $\ce{HCl}$, the total pressure of $\ce{HCl}$ should be $750$ Torr = $0.986$ atm. But it is not so high, as a small amount $x$ of $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{NH_3}$ must react to maintain the equilibrium constant. One may write that :

$$K_p = (0.329 - x)(0.986 - x)= 0.108 \space \text{atm}^2$$

The solution of this equation is :  $x = 0.18$. So the final pressures of $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{NH_3}$ are :

$$p(\ce{NH_3}) = 0.329 - 0.108 = 0.211 \space \text{atm}$$
$$p(\ce{HCl}) = 0.986 - 0.108 = 0.878 \space \text{atm}$$

The total pressure is $0.211 + 0.878 = 1.089 \space \text{atm}$

Comment: Thank you very much, your response has been very helpful, the only thing that the value of x gives 0.193.